# Verify whether continuous mapping theorem is applicable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, continuity

Consider we have $X_n \overset{a.s.}{\to} x$ where $X_n = [A_n, B_n, C_n]$ are $\mathbb{R}^3$-valued random variables, for all $n$ $A_n,B_n,C_n > 0$ almost surely, $A_n,B_n,C_n$ may be dependent or not, and $x = [a, b, ab]$.

Is the function $g: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}, [p,q,r] \mapsto \frac{pq}{r}$ continuous in Heine's definition such that the continuous mapping theorem is applicable, i.e. $g(X_n) \overset{a.s.}{\to} \frac{ab}{ab}=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Take e.g. $X_n=[\frac2{n},\frac2{n},\frac1{n^2}]$ and $x=[0,0,0]$.

Then $X_{n}\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\to}x$.

However $g(X_n)=4\neq1$ for each $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the counter-example! What are the ways to show that a function is continuous in Heine's sense, hence the continuous mapping theorem is applicable? I mean, a counter-example suffices to disprove it for a given function, but what are the constructive ways to assure a function indeed is Heine-continuous?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not familiar with Heine-continuous.